# pandoc: markdown to html embedding PDF using <iframe> or <object> instead of <embed>

Tags: markdown, pandoc

I am trying to embed some PDF's into my HTML files and pandoc uses the older  tags instead of newer  or . It wouldnt bother me that much, but the embedded pdfs end up being very small and not scaled, so I want to modify the way it handles the .pdf files.

Is there any easy way to do that?

Thank you!

Comment: Can you give some example code? Best would be to see the input, the current output, and the expected output. Only then can we come up with an answer that will truly do what you need.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.